# Hibernate relationship OneToMany(fetch=Lazy) using array of value

Tags: java, hibernate

Studying hibernate with spring, I've got one question. How can I create relationship OneToMany(fetch=Lazy) using array of value?

In table `Path.categoryIds` saved a few `Place.id`s as string, which using `@Converter` converting from `String` to `int` array.

So, how to fill List "places" using `int[] placeIds` values?

```
Place table
- int id
- String name

Path table
- int id
- String place_ids (Place.id`s written by comma (ex:"1,2,3"))

@Entity
@Table(name="place")
public class Place {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="path")
public class Path {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="category_ids")
    @Convert(converter = PlaceIdsConverter.class) // "1,2,3" -> [1,2,3]
    private int[] placeIds;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) // ???, how to fill using values    from placeIds
    private List<Place> places;
}
```

However, case with additional table for ManyToMany relationship is impossible by other causes. :(